# differnce between npm correlation-id and uuid?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angular, npm

May I know whats the difference between  `uuid` and `correlation-id` npm packages?  `correlation-id` internally using `uuid` package only..

In what scenario  `correlation-id` is much better to use than `uuid`?

**Note:**

Am not using nodejs in my application, instead using Java as my Backend, and using Angular as Front end,  While making request, I need to pass some header with some unique value, then which package should I prefer in angular?: correlation-id or uuid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you want unique identifiers for your server objects, you can use `uuid`.
- If you want to keep track of a chain of functions calls of each request in your node server, `correlation-id` can help with that.

Except having `id` in the name, they are different. `correlation-id` can use `uuid` to generate ids that can be used to uniquely identify an async call chain.

Comment: Am not using nodejs in my application, instead using Java as my Backend, and using Angular as Front end,  While making request, I need to pass some header with some unique value, then which package should I prefer in angular?: correlation-id or uuid?

Comment: In that case, it is `uuid`, @john!

Answer (score 0):

The underlying implementation generates a `uuid`.

The core difference is that it can return the same uuid if called from the same context - for e.g `correlator.withId` method mentioned in [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/correlation-id) returns the same uuid.

`correlation-id` is used in request logging. For ex. Express has a [middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-correlation-id) which attaches a unique correlation-id to each request which can be obtained using `req.correlationId()`.

If called from anywhere where the `req` object is present it will return the same correlation-id. Hence it can trace a particular request.

Comment: Am not using nodejs in my application, instead using Java as my Backend, and using Angular as Front end,  While making request, I need to pass some header with some unique value, then which package should I prefer in angular?: correlation-id or uuid?